# using copy destination vba between workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns, copy-paste

Been working a project using recorded macros to complete copying and pasting between workbooks. Recorded macros has been working BUT, when reading the forums people are stating copy/paste method takes more time for macro to run and is very inefficient.  So I'm trying to sound out a copy destination vba line that would copy several columns starting from Range(A2:G2000) and then paste to range area starting at (B6:H2000).  I'm not good at this and trying to learn more efficiency.  Two things here come to mind.  A simple copy and paste method which I have working. BUT would utilize the straight source = destination.  Could this be done?  After reading this you may see another issue. Why have down to Row 2000 selected and copy/pasted?  You are correct in your thinking. Some reports(txt files) have 100 rows, some 300, none more than 1000 but I'm overdoing the copy selection because I'm won't be sure about future txt files. I was thinking if you could just select the column down to the last row used would be cool. This is way beyond me.  I'd be happy just a new way to copy/paste efficiently.
I would appreciate any help that anyone could offer.  let me know what you think.
Thanks
Boomer

```
enter code here
   Sub import_data()
   '
   '
    'import_data
    '
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '
   'Opens the txt file in excel - text delimited and leaves file open until 
   we close at bottom of code. There is no        'name for this workbook.

    Workbooks.OpenText (Module33.FileDir + "\cf_data.txt"), Origin:=437, _
    StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
    ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False _
    , Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), 
      _
     Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), 
   TrailingMinusNumbers:=True


  'The line below is where I'm selecting data from the current opened 
  workbook and copying to another workbook

   ActiveWindow.Sheet1.Range("A2:G2000").Copy 
    Destination:=Workbooks("Auto_Data.xlsm").Sheet2.Range       ("B6:H2000")



   'This info below is a (recorded marco).  All works if I rem out the above 
    line and open up all the below lines

    '    Range("A2:G2000").Select
    '    Selection.Copy
    '    Windows("Auto_Data.xlsm").Activate
    '    Sheet2.Select
   '    Range("B6:H6").Select
    '    ActiveSheet.Paste
    '    Selection.AutoFilter
    '    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    '    ActiveWindow.ActivateNext
    '    ActiveWindow.Close
    '    Range("B4").Select
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   End Sub
```

Comment: Show your code. You've left a lot of questions unanswered but your code will explain those.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include your code. It's undecipherable as a comment.

Comment: Click [Edit] to [edit] your question. Paste the code in then select all of it again and tap ctrl+K.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it pasted in there.  please have a look when you have some time. Hope it's not too confusing.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

A direct value transfer is typically faster than a copy and uses less memory since it doesn't involve the clipboard.

```
Sub import_data()

    dim lr as long, arr as variant
    dim wb1 as workbook

    set wb1 = Workbooks.OpenText(filename:=Module33.FileDir & "\cf_data.txt"), Origin:=437, _
                                 StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
                                 ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, _
                                 Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), _
                                 Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1)), 
                                 TrailingMinusNumbers:=True)

    with wb1.sheets(1)

        lr = .range("A:G").Find(what:="*", after:=.range("A1"), searchorder:=xlbyrows, _
                                searchdirection:=xlprevious).row
        .range(.cells(2, "A"), .cells(lr, "G")).value

    end with

    wb1.close

    Workbooks("Auto_Data.xlsm").Sheet2.Range("B6").resize(ubound(arr, 1), ubound(arr, 2)) = arr

end sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have been looking through this.  I plugged the code into the app and I'm receiving an [Compile Error: Expected :end of statement].  The error that this seems to be hitting on is the     set wb1 = Workbooks.OpenText(filename:=Module33.FileDir & "\cf_data.txt"), Origin:=437, _     And is highlighting the comma directly behind the [ "\cf_data.txt"), <--- ]    I drew the arrow for pointing. That's not in the code.  The entire 4-5 lines or (text delimited transaction) is all in RED color.  When I take the [ set sb1 = ] out everything goes black and seems good.

Comment: I went back and confirmed syntax for extra spaces with that area and all looks good.  Not sure what the code is wanting with Expected :end of statement??  I have not been able to test the code as of yet.  Please let me know of some troubleshooting steps I could take with this.  Thanks again for helping me with this.

Comment: Hello User11138753,  I trying to paste new code for you to look at.  Since the above came with an error inside the 'open text file in excel area,  I wanted to push the code  down  [  Set wb1 =  ]  to just above  [  With wb1.Sheets(1)   ]  & added [  Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook   ].  When testing, the text delimited file opens in excel fine. And then excel breaks.  With the highlighted line being  [ .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "G")).Value  ]   and the error being [ Run-time Error 438:  Object doesn't support this property or method.  ]

Comment: Yeah sorry for not catching onto this commenting and code copy/pasting. So, the above code my thoughts, since the open text file delimited area was opening the file correctly, I moved down your WB1 variable set to just below. and added ThisWorkbook. Was thinking that the xls file is open so we can set wb1 = ThisWorkbook, then continue to wb1.Sheets(1). May be wrong. just thinking. Code Runs, and stops at [ .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "G")).Value ] highlights entire line with the mentioned error.  I'm reading the code and trying to make sense of it. The light hasn't turned on yet, It Will